# How do you fix a gcc compile 127 error? sudo apt-get install g++ doesn't work

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, gcc

*emphasized text*when I try to run a program I get the following error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ make
g++ -Wall -Wno-switch -I. -g   -c -o pass.o pass.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [pass.o] Error 127
```

I couldn't get gcc 4.8.2 installed because it said it couldn't find it. I did install 4.8

I did the following to install gcc

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-f/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

next I did

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 60 --slave     /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

the only thing I can think of is I don't have 4.8 when I type the command *gcc -v* it says
    gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)

ok I run:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
g++ set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 293 not upgraded.

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ g++ -v
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
* g++
* pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ g++ --help | grep version
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
* g++
* pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ g++ --version
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
* g++
* pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ^C
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

this command installs

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev 4.4 (I would like 4.8)

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
cpp-4.4 gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base
Suggested packages:
gcc-4.4-locales g++-4.4-multilib gcc-4.4-doc libstdc++6-4.4-dbg
gcc-4.4-multilib libmudflap0-4.4-dev libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
libmudflap0-dbg libcloog-ppl0 libppl-c2 libppl7 libstdc++6-4.4-doc

The following NEW packages will be installed:
cpp-4.4 g++-4.4 gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base libstdc++6-4.4-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 292 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 33.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gcc-4.4-base i386 4.4.7-1ubuntu2 [12.0 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main cpp-4.4 i386 4.4.7-1ubuntu2 [3,606 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gcc-4.4 i386 4.4.7-1ubuntu2 [3,079 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libstdc++6-4.4-dev i386 4.4.7-1ubuntu2 [1,494 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.4 i386 4.4.7-1ubuntu2 [4,780 kB]
Fetched 13.0 MB in 3s (3,563 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.4-base.
(Reading database ... 222776 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gcc-4.4-base (from .../gcc-4.4-base_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-4.4.
Unpacking cpp-4.4 (from .../cpp-4.4_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.4.
Unpacking gcc-4.4 (from .../gcc-4.4_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++6-4.4-dev.
Unpacking libstdc++6-4.4-dev (from .../libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-4.4.
Unpacking g++-4.4 (from .../g++-4.4_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up gcc-4.4-base (4.4.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up cpp-4.4 (4.4.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gcc-4.4 (4.4.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up g++-4.4 (4.4.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libstdc++6-4.4-dev (4.4.7-1ubuntu2) ...
```

I have tried replacing 4.4 with 4.8 but it doesn't work. More importantly after using the 4.4 command above I still get the 127 error.

I have been learning to program for the past month so when you answer please know I'm newer than new, and don't understand a lot if anything.

Comment: Can you please run a `locate g++` and a `whereis g++`

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `g++` or some similarly named package to compile c++ code.

Comment: I did that but it didn't help much. Please take a look at my updated question details

Answer (score 2):

Install g++. This can be done e.g. by

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Not sure whether you really need a particular version. In most cases system default should be ok for it.

Comment: I did that but it didn't help much. Please take a look at my updated question details

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the g++. Check if you don't have any extra space or newline characters. If everything follows ***Makefile*** standard it should be ok. Additionally, check if you have specified the path correctly.

I hope I'll help somebody else, because I think you're over that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the build-essentials by executing `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. That is the error#1 if you have a fresh installation and want to compile something